# Is the set of integers represented by a quadratic form of non-fundamental discriminant a subset of the rep. set of a form of fundamental discriminant?

Tags: nt.number-theory, binary-quadratic-forms, discriminant

I am currently working with positive-definite, reduced, primitive, integral binary quadratic forms, and I have noticed something interesting.

Conjecture:
Let $Q$ be a form of non-fundamental discriminant $\Delta$. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ be the associated quadratic field of discriminant $\Delta_K$ (which we note is fundamental). Let $R=\{m: m=Q(x,y), x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, the set of integers represented by $Q$. Then $R\subseteq R_K$, where $R_K=\{m: m=Q_K(x,y), x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ for a fixed form $Q_K$ of fundamental discriminant $\Delta_K$.

Example: Let $Q(x,y)=x^2+8y^2$. Then $\Delta=-32$. Let $R=\{m: m=Q(x,y), x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Then $R\subseteq\{m: m=x^2+2y^2, x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

This seems like a very basic fact about fundamental and non-fundamental discriminants, but I cannot find it anywhere in the literature. The only thing that has been suggested to me is the term maximal quadratic form, but I can't find that either. Is this a known theorem?

Answer (score 4):

This is true, of course. The book you want is Binary Quadratic Forms by D. A. Buell. He talks about how, given some discriminant $\Delta$ and class number(primitive forms) $h(\Delta),$ we can predict $h(4 \Delta)$ and $h(p^2 \Delta).$ Pages 117-118, let me check.

I did find  [slides for a 2010 talk by Buell](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/MINI/2010/buell.pdf). It is not about your question, however the style is quite reminiscent of his book.

In the reverse direction (Kaplansky used to do these two variables at a time, fine as you have just two) 
we can, given discriminant $\Delta p^2,$ we can find a form $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ equivalent to the original that is now of the form (with $a$ not divisible by $p$) $$ \langle a,bp,cp^2 \rangle \; \; ,   $$ which descends to $$ \langle a,b,c \rangle \; \; .   $$

Let's see, if $$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + b p x y + c p^2 y^2  $$ and
$$  g(x,y)  = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, $$ then
$$ f(x,y) = g(x,py) \; , $$
making your subset idea explicit.

This is page 119 in Buell, with a repeat of the comment that the one-to-many maps he gives from discriminant $\Delta$ upwards to $\Delta p^2$ is surjective.

In short, Chapter 7, section 1, pages 109-119 in Buell. The section title is "Nonfundamental Discriminants."

I see, students of Pete L. Clark not long ago: https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04877